# TestNG - Soft Assert

Tags: java, testng

I have a `@Test` setup on a script, that runs with some `soft asserts`.

However, I am running into a problem with the placement of the `assertAll`. I want all of the `URLs` to go through before the `assertAll`. Is this possible or is another recommended approach?

```
@Test
public static void checkUrl(String requestUrl, String expectedUrl){

    SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert ();

    try {

        URL obj = new URL(requestUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
        conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
        conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "google.com");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Request URL ... " + requestUrl);


        boolean redirect = false;

        // normally, 3xx is redirect
        int status = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
                    || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
                    || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER) redirect = true;
        }

        System.out.println("Response Code ... " + status);
        if (redirect) {

            // get redirect url from "location" header field
            String redirectUrl = conn.getHeaderField("Location");

            // get the cookie if need, for login
            String cookies = conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");

            // open the new connnection again
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(redirectUrl).openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);
            conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
            conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
            conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "google.com");

            System.out.println("Redirect to URL : " + redirectUrl);
            //Assert.assertEquals (redirectUrl, expectedUrl);
            softAssert.assertEquals (redirectUrl, expectedUrl, "Expected URL does not match"
                    + requestUrl);
        } else {
            //org.testng.Assert.assertTrue (redirect);
            softAssert.assertTrue (redirect, "Please check the status for " + requestUrl);
             System.out.println("** Please check status for " + requestUrl);
             System.out.println("************************************************");
             System.out.println("************************************************");
        }


    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use case that you are looking for, kind of defeats the purpose of `SoftAssert`. `SoftAssert` was basically introduced in TestNG, so that you can gather all the assertions, throughout one `@Test` method but fail the test method only at the end (when you invoke `assertAll()`).

A data driven `@Test` method is basically a `@Test` method that runs **"n"** times (each iteration is running with a different set of data). So it doesn't make sense for you to try and leverage `SoftAssert` and invoke its `assertAll()` on the last iteration. Because if you do that, it would basically boil down to only the last iteration failing.

So if you are looking at re-running tests by using the `testng-failed.xml` then it would contain only the index of the last iteration (Which is kind of absurd, because it wasn't the last iteration that actually failed).

So ideally speaking, you should make use of `SoftAssert` only within the scope of a single iteration. That means you instantiate a `SoftAssert` object within a `@Test` method, invoke a bunch of `assertXXX()` calls, and at the end of the method you invoke `assertAll()`.

All said and done, if you are still looking for a sample that would show you how to do this, here's a sample.

First we define an interface that lets me set the size of the data provider provided data set as an attribute to the test class.

```java
public interface IDataSet {
    void setSize(int size);
}
```

The test class looks like below

```
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.TestInstance;
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class SoftAssertDemo implements IDataSet {
  private int size;
  private SoftAssert assertion = new SoftAssert();
  private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(1);

  @Override
  public void setSize(int size) {
    this.size = size;
  }

  @Test(dataProvider = "dp")
  public void testMethod(int number) {
    if ((number % 2) == 0) {
      assertion.fail("Simulating a failure for " + number);
    }
    if (counter.getAndIncrement() == size) {
      assertion.assertAll();
    }
  }

  @DataProvider(name = "dp")
  public Object[][] getData(@TestInstance Object object) {
    Object[][] data = new Object[][] {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}};
    if (object instanceof IDataSet) {
      ((IDataSet) object).setSize(data.length);
    }
    return data;
  }
}
```

Caveats in this approach:

1. A test class should have only one `@DataProvider` method in it because the data provider is passing on the size of the data set back to the test class instance. So if you have 2 or more data providers, there's a chance of data race going on, wherein one data provider overwrites the other one.
2. If you want to house 2 or more data providers, then you would need to ensure that those `@Test` methods that are powered by the data providers, dont run in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I used @DataProvider and just added the Soft Assert All into the Test method after I called the Method with the Soft Assert True and Soft Assert Equals in it.

Comment: Krishnan - does this sound like a bad use of testng to you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56300662/how-do-i-validate-multiple-inputs-for-a-function

Answer (score 0):

I used a @DataProvider and @Test method. The @Test method took the String[][] from the @DataProvider. I then didn't need the for each loop. I just put the Assert All after the checkUrl method that has the Assert True and Assert Equals.

```
           @Test(dataProvider = “Urls”)
           public static void TestURLRedirectCheck2(String RURL, String EURL){
           checkUrl(RURL, EURL);
           softAssert.assertAll ();
           }
```